# Configure best bets or result promotion in Solr/Lucene

Tags: search, lucene, solr

I'm using Solr/Lucene as search engine for my application. I require that some results (known as best bets) show every time the user asks for certain queries. Does anyone knows how to configure this in Solr/Lucene?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [QueryElevationComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent).